# Using null as value in Set.fold generates NoSuchElement Exception

Tags: scala

In my `Scala` code, I am generating a `Strings` from elements of a `Set` and then store in `Cassandra`. I notice that if I use `null` as initial value of accumulator then when I fetch this record, I get error `java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present`. But if I use `""` then I don't

This works ok.

```
Tuple3(tagsToStore.tagsOfInterest.fold("")((a:String,b:String)=>{if(a != "") a+";"+b else b}),
            tagsToStore.questionCreatedTag.fold("")((a:String,b:String)=>{if(a != "") a+";"+b else b}),
            tagsToStore.questionAnsweredTag.fold("")((a:String,b:String)=>{if(a != "") a+";"+b else b}))
        } else Tuple3("","","") //I thought to use null instead of "" but that gave me error when fetching the profile Reason java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
```

This doesn't

```
Tuple3(tagsToStore.tagsOfInterest.fold(null)((a:String,b:String)=>{if(a != "") a+";"+b else b}),
            tagsToStore.questionCreatedTag.fold(null)((a:String,b:String)=>{if(a != "") a+";"+b else b}),
            tagsToStore.questionAnsweredTag.fold()((a:String,b:String)=>{if(a != "") a+";"+b else b}))
        } else Tuple3(null,null,null) //I thought to use null instead of "" but that gave me error when fetching the profile Reason java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
```

The data model is

```
case class ...(tagsOfInterest:Set[String],
               questionCreatedTag:Set[String],
               questionAnsweredTag:Set[String]
              )
```

Why does using `null` throws the exception?

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1):

The precise reason for the `NoSuchElementException` cannot be given without Scala and JVM version information and the stack trace (and on Scala 2.13 with a recent OpenJDK8, I can't reproduce the issue: `null` when treated as a `String` gets coerced into `"null"`).

Generally, however, outside of sections of code directly interacting with libraries written in other languages, `null` is generally not encountered in idiomatic Scala code.  This in turn means that `null` is not treated as being in the domain of a lot of functions in the standard library, so weird things can happen.

Your desired behavior can be expressed more idiomatically:

```
(tagsToStore.tagsOfInterest.mkString(";"),
 tagsToStore.questionCreatedTag.mkString(";"),
 tagsToStore.questionAnsweredTag.mkString(";"))
```

Side note: the idiomatic way of constructing a `TupleN` is `(x, y, z)`, not `Tuple3(x, y, z)` (the latter is what the compiler expands the former to).